# Command Prompt returns "The syntax of the command is incorrect" when running 'ant all'

Tags: ant, command-prompt, jnativehook

I am trying to compile [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) by following [this](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Compiling) tutorial. I followed all the steps (I am running on windows and have used Cygwin in some parts) until the **Building** section (running `ant all` command). I have added environment variables as follows:

```
ANT_HOME  ->  C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.5
JAVA_HOME  -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

And added the following to path:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

However, whenever I try to run the `ant all` command (with the default command prompt and as an administrator) I get this error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I got the same error when trying to run the batch file from the command prompt:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin
ant.bat
```

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

ps: when I run `java -version` command it returns:

`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)`

Comment: What's the output from echo %PATH%? You should be adding %ANT_HOME%\bin and %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH by the way, as then when you add a different Ant or Java you can just update JAVA_HOME/ANT_HOME.

Comment: After adding `%ANT_HOME%\bin`  and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to path, this is what I got from `echo %PATH%` : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;`  along with other system variables. But I still get the same error when running `ant`.

Comment: Did you also run into this error before adding those locations to PATH, as per your last comment? First thing I notice is that you have duplicate entries for the Java and Ant bin directories. Also, it shouldn't be necessary to have JAVA_HOME listed in PATH, just its bin.

Comment: Also, maybe check this out: https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@ant.apache.org/msg37855.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives me the same error. I have tried all combinations (adding the full path to the bin in PATH , replacing them with`%ANT_HOME%\bin` and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and adding both at the same time) but still. Interestingly the `java` command works fine as I edited in the post, but the `ant ` still doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to redownload the ant executables. Make sure you remove the duplicates from the PATH as well.